# NSIS - Desktop Shortcut For All Users

Tags: nsis

How can I create desktop shortcuts for all user while installing a package?

Comment: This usually means only the admin can delete your shortcut, uncool!

Answer (score 11):

NSIS supports several of the common/shared [special folders](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#varconstant):

```
SetShellVarContext all
CreateShortcut "$desktop\myapp.lnk" "$instdir\myapp.exe"
```

This code assumes you are [elevated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825202/3501)...

Comment: This works for me on Windows 10.  However, it doesn't seem to do the trick for a similar shortcut in the 'start programs' folder (`$SMPROGRAMS`).

Comment: In MUI2, you have to `!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_BEGIN Application` to set $SMPROGRAMS. When you are done `_END`

Answer (score 2):

With `!include NTProfiles.nsh` [1] you can create a shortcut in the folder `"${ProfilePathAllUsers}\Desktop"`.

[1] - http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NT_Profile_Paths

Comment: Hi Robert.. Thanks for the solution.. but it seems to b not working in my package maker 1.1.. Is there any constraints bcoz of version.? I adden NTProfiles.nsh in Include Folder and given the path as u mentioned...                     Thanks..

Comment: This code uses undocumented registry values! NSIS has native support for the shared desktop folder so this kind of thing is not required nor recommended!