# Nsis shortcuts for different users

Tags: unicode, nsis, shortcut

Advice Nsis – windows7
I have two users on the same computer (Admin and standard), I will be running my nsis installer when logged in to the standard user. My problem is that I need to create shortcuts on both desktops!! 
Example

Standard User - Desktop
 - Shortcut 1
 - Shortcut 2
 - Shortcut 3

Admin User - Desktop
 - Shortcut 2
 - Shortcut 4

I’m new to nsis- I have managed to create the Shortcut on the standard user account - If it helps I know the admin username and password.

[NSIS - Desktop Shortcut For All Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501193/nsis-desktop-shortcut-for-all-users) 
I saw this link but it does not seem to be working 
 When I try

```
CreateShortCut "${ProfilePathAllUsers}\Desktop\simpleApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\ApplicationsLocation\ Applications.simpleApp.Host.exe"
```

I fear I may be going in the wrong direction-
Im also using Unicode Nsis

Any Advice will be welcome - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to another users profile without administrator rights so [make sure you are elevated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825202/3501).

Creating a shortcut for another user is wrong IMHO. If you want to create a shortcut for all users you can do:

```
; This code assumes you are elevated...
SetShellVarContext all
CreateShortcut "$desktop\myapp.lnk" "$instdir\myapp.exe"
```

Knowing the username/password would indeed help if you really wanted to do it for a single user; you would have to call [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the system plugin to get the path (Or the code you linked to but that uses undocumented stuff).

Comment: Thanks for your Reply anders, its a requirement that some applications can only be run if your an admin..